# SharePoint Central Administration not working

Tags: sharepoint, iis-7.5, sharepoint-2013

I installed SharePoint Server 2013 on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 64-bit.
   Database is SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2. After a successfull installation 
   when I ran the configuration wizard it was also successfull. But in the last 
   step I could'nt get Central Administratiopn. I got an error.

> Service Unavailable

---

> HTTP Error 503. The service is unavailable.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the corresponding web application pool in IIS that is hosting the Central Administration?

Sounds like it is not running. And did you perform a restart after the installation process succeeded?